Tiempo de vida de sesión en CodeIgniter 4
Tengo una duda/problema con la vida de la sesión en CodeIgniter 4, la sesión "ci_session", antes programaba de manera nativa en PHP (versión 7.3).
Encontré la manera de "matar" la sesión de manera programada, cosa que es sencillo con:
public int $expiration = 7200; // Archivo Session.php (App/Config/Session.php)

Lo que genera que la sesión muera a las 2 horas (7200 segundos), si le cambiamos ese valor muere pasado el tiempo que determinó en segundos, por ejemplo 10, 15 segundos.
public int $expiration = [Otra cantidad de segundos como 10 o 15 por ejemplo];

Estuve investigando y si se coloca 0 como valor:
public int $expiration = 0;

La sesión la "mato" al cerrar el navegador, cosa que es cierto o... ¡Eso quiero pensar!
¿Porqué digo estó? Bueno, porque si dejo el valor en 7200, cierro y abro el navegador en mi aplicación CodeIgniter, la sesión habrá muerto ¿Me explico? cuando se supone que debe seguir viva ¿O no funciona así de esa manera?
También leí que puede ser otra configuración que haga una sobreescritura o "Override" no sé si sea la manera correcta de decirle, estuve investigando y ahí mismo en "App/Config" existe un archivo "Cookie.php" que contiene:
public $expires = 0;

O en el archivo env.php:
# cookie.prefix = ''
# cookie.expires = 7200
# cookie.path = '/'
# cookie.domain = ''
# cookie.secure = false
# cookie.httponly = false
# cookie.samesite = 'Lax'
# cookie.raw = false

Donde obviamente está comentado con #, pensé que ambos debería estar con el mismo valor, 7200 o 0, pero tampoco funciono, estoy un poco confundido en como funciona.
Revise DevTool >> Application >> Cookies >> Dominio (localhost), me aparece lo siguiente:

¿Alguien sería tan amable de explicarme, también que me indique como puedo setear una alertar para extender la vida o bien que se cierre, algo como "Deseas extender tu tiempo en la aplicación"?

Puede ser que estés abriendo el navegador sin ningún dato? Te soy sincero no tengo ni idea de codeigniter pero si se que en muchos lenguajes de programación se te habré un navegador de manera automática al ejecutar el programa y este suele estar abierto en modo incógnito o sin perfil etc... Por lo que no tendrá ninguna sesión, revisa que las pruebas las estas haciendo en tu navegador personal

que dice el php_info ???

session.cookie_lifetime = 0, no entiendo, seguí revisando cosas en CI4, también en php.ini de XAMPP pero no funciona... ¿Porqué es demasiado complicado?

Revisando tu imagen se encuentran 2 sesiones iniciadas una es desde el dominio localhost y otra desde 127.0.0.0, según la fecha de expiración la sesión de localhost tiene la configuración de $expiration con un valor positivo y la sesión de 127.0.0.1 tiene la configuración de $expiration = 0;

Posible Causa

Configuración de Cookies del Navegador: Algunos navegadores pueden estar configurados para eliminar cookies al cerrarse, lo cual puede afectar las sesiones.
La configuración de timezome: PHP y CondeIgniter tiene una configuración de la zona horaria la cual comúnmente es UTC, esto puede tener conflicto con la hora que establece para la expiración de la sesión y la hora del equipo donde se abre la aplicación, por lo cual debes configurar timezone a tu hora local, en Codeigniter 4 esta configuración la encuentras en app/Config/App.php como public string $appTimezone = 'UTC';.

Configuraciones
En cuestión de la configuración del archivo env y los archivos de la carpeta app/Config, el framework primero revisa que existe el archivo .env y que contenga las configuraciones descomentadas y toma esa configuración, si no las encuentra busca en los archivos de configuración de la carpeta app/Config y toma esa configuración. No necesariamente hay que configurar ambos archivos.

Revise la configuración del navegador, no tiene seteado que elimine las cookies al cerrar el navegador.
Si, están las dos sesiones corregí esa parte, ahora solo existe "ci_session", hasta ahí todo bien.
Un problema que tenía era que la sesión tronaba a las dos horas, le anduve moviendo y logre que la sesión tronara hasta que se cerrará el navegador, es algo confuso, configue el "expires" en 0, lo que genera eso antes mencionado, pero si coloco 7200, la sesión no debería tronar aunque cierre el navegador, ahora solo me falta corregir eso ¡No entiendo muy bien, pero bueno la sesión ahora dura!
